# no me funciona flex-direction

Tags: html, flexbox

estoy haciendo una de las prácticas de freecodecamp y he hecho un sidebar y el contenido main con flexbox  con direción row.

Ahora me gustaría que ese sidebar cuando se ve en el móvil se viese desde arriba de forma vertical, para ello simplemente cambie a flex-direction column pero no me funciona :( .

A ver si alguien me puede orientar. (he dejado solo la parte estructural del html para que no os comais todo el rollaco de parrafos etc..)

es mi primera vez en stackoverflow perdonad si fallo en algo a la hora de presentar la pregunta. Muchas gracias !!!

```
<body>

  <nav id="navbar">
    
  </nav>

  <main id="main-doc">
    
    </section>

  </main>
</body>
```

my css

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#navbar {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ed59ff;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
}

.enlace-menu {
  margin: 20% 0px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}

#enlace-img {
  margin: 5% 0px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}
#main-doc {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: 20%;
}

p{
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

li{
    font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

h2{
  color:red;
}

.enlace-menu a{
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.main-section a{
  color: #ed59ff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
  flex-direction: column;
  
}
  #main-doc {
 

}
  
  #navbar {

  
}
  
}
```

Comment: Intenta cambiar el @media por lo que pone aqui en su primer ejemplo, a ver si asi lo solucionas: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: gracias por contestar ! 
Sigue sin funcionar, probé con mi código de antes a cambiar el color del background y si cogía el @media bien; cambiaba cuando el screen era más pequeño pero no me cambiaba la dirección del flexbox. 

Lo curioso es que he probado a cambiar directamente fuera del media query y cuando cambio de row a column no pasa absolutamente nada D:

Comment: Bueno, de flex poco puedo ayudarte, lo del @media era lo que alguna vez sí que habia funcionado para la visualización en dispositivos moviles Android, pues sin esa sintaxis que te he pasado en el enlace no se veia bien. Mírate si acaso esta explicación por si le ves algun sentido a lo que te está pasando:  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox